# Python setuptools exclude dependencies when installing

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

Python setuptools allows you to [specify optional dependencies](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#optional-dependencies), but does it allow you to do something in the inverse?

For example, let's say I have a list of dependencies in `my_package` like below:

- numpy
- pandas

So if I installed the package with `pip install my_package`, it would also install these two dependencies.

However, for certain use cases, a user may not need `pandas`. So I would want to do something like `pip install my_package[~pandas]` or something like that to instruct pip to not install pandas.

Is this something that is currently supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not currently supported - extras are strictly additive. It has been proposed several times, but the discussions never seem to get anywhere.

The latest discussion is here:

[Proposal - expanding optional dependencies to support opt-out of recommended/default installables](https://discuss.python.org/t/proposal-expanding-optional-dependencies-to-support-opt-out-of-recommended-default-installables/26617).

As a workaround, you can use:

```
pip install --no-deps my_package
```

But this would exclude *every* dependency, including pandas. You'd have to find and install the other dependencies manually.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, while it is possible to install optional dependencies with, for example

```
pip install my_package[super,cool]
```

the opposite, keeping from installing dependencies (`!cool`) is not possible. Wim already mentioned the [`--no-deps`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-no-deps) workaround. Another workaround might be to provide two versions, `my_package` and `my_package_vanilla` with different dependencies. Then user could install, for example:

- `my_package` to install all default dependencies needed by the average user
- `my_package_vanilla` to install just the bare bones version of `my_package` (perhaps even non-functional without extras?)
- `my_package_vanilla[pandas,super,cool]` installing three sets of extra dependencies chosen by the user.